# Convert a List of Objects to ExpandableObject in propertygrid C#

Tags: c#, propertygrid

Hello I know this might be marked as a duplicate it also might not but I am trying to make a list of objects displays as a there own expandable object in a property grid.

I have two classes a SodeAttribute Class:

```
public class SodeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of attribute   
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Value of attribute  
    /// </summary>
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and a SodeElement Class:

```
public class SodeElement
{
    //[Browsable(false)]
    /// <summary>
    /// Type of sode element    
    /// </summary>
    public string Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of Sode Attributes
    /// </summary>
    public List<SodeAttribute> SodeAttributes = new List<SodeAttribute>();

    /// <summary>
    /// List of Sode Elements
    /// </summary>
    public List<SodeElement> ChildElements = new List<SodeElement>();
}
```

which contains a list of SodeAttributes and a List of SodeElements. this basically represents an XML structure in like this:

```
 <SimObject Name="Wind Sock">
    <Placement Lat="47.1821" Lon="7.4188" Alt="0#AGL" Hdg="0.0"/>           
    <Model SimTitle="12bPilot_SODE_Windsock_Slow">      
        <VariableDrivenRotation Variable="WindDirection" Axis="HEADING" Animated="No"/>         
        <ConditionalVisibility Variable="WindSpeed" Value="0-14"/>
    </Model>
    <Model SimTitle="12bPilot_SODE_Windsock_Medium_Speed">      
        <VariableDrivenRotation Variable="WindDirection" Axis="HEADING" Animated="No"/>         
        <ConditionalVisibility Variable="WindSpeed" Value="15-28"/>
    </Model>
    <Model SimTitle="12bPilot_SODE_Windsock_Fast">      
        <VariableDrivenRotation Variable="WindDirection" Axis="HEADING" Animated="No"/>         
        <ConditionalVisibility Variable="WindSpeed" Value="29-60"/>
    </Model>            
</SimObject>
```

where the attributes of the XML are stored as a SodeAttribute Object in the list of Sode attributes and any child Elements of the root SimObject is stored in the List of SodeElements for example, the  and the child element

So in this XML the SodeElement has 3 child SodeElements and  1 Sode Attribute.

I would, for example, have any child element of SimObject for example Model to be shown as an ExpandableObject and any attributes be displayed as properties in that expandable object and any other element in that model element "model" be displayed as an expandable object for example like this

Example 1:
[image]

Example 2:
[image]

I have tried attempting this many times and I think I am in a loop so I would love a working example. Thank you!

Comment: Could you try to show what you expect to see with the XML data (instead of the address thing)?

Comment: The pictures at the bottom is what I want the property grid to show basically for example in the last picture where address2 is would be model  in model would be property SimTitle with value 12bPilot_SODE_Windsock_Slow and in this model expandable object create an expandable object with the name